# How can I block the search box animation on the Wirecutter website with uBlock Origin?

Tags: adblock, animation, advertisements, ublock-origin, ublock

Wirecutter recommends the uBlock Origin ad blocker. As I understand, in addition to advertisements, ad blockers can also be used to block annoyances. At the top of each guide on Wirecutter, I see a search box with an animation. The text in the animation changes, "Show me the research on...", "How can we help?", "Help me decide on..." etc. This animation distracts from reading the guides. How can I block the search box animation on the Wirecutter website with uBlock Origin?

I checked the account settings and the help section of the Wirecutter website. I emailed the New York Times, but several months have passed, and they have not replied. I searched on Super User, and I found other questions related to uBlock Origin, so this question is on topic. Please find attached a screenshot of the Wirecutter website with the search box circled in red.

- ["Our Favorite Ad Blockers and Browser Extensions to Protect
  Privacy" on Wirecutter](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/our-favorite-ad-blockers-and-browser-extensions-to-protect-privacy/)
- [Wirecutter](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter)
- ["Wirecutter" on AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/software/the-wirecutter/about/)
- ["Filter for uBlock" on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1341831/filter-for-ublock)

[image: Search Box on Wirecutter]

Comment: Right click and Block Element?

Comment: For animations and other scripts, NoScript or ScriptMonkey (that's still at thing, right?) are probably better. uBlock is about blocking ads, and that's not an ad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uBlock is not the best tool for removing animations and often userscripts can do it more easily/elegantly.

In this case though it's doable easily by removing the text elements entirely. For example:

```
nytimes.com###search-input-primary_nav ~ div
```

This disables all `div` siblings of the `#search-input-primary-div` search box.

Removing only animation is also doable but more convoluted, as it requires messing with way more specific CSS properties of those `div`s:

[image: CSS properties]

so IMO it's not worth messing with to just keep some not too useful static text.

Comment: Perfect! I navigated to uBlock Origin –> Open the dashboard –> My filters. Then I copy-pasted the filter from your answer and clicked Apply changes. This blocked the animated text in the search box on the Wirecutter website. I tested that searching still works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked